# How to load a custom cell from xib but keeping outlets inside the cell instead of ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Till now, I was doing something like this:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
     self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
     if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        NSArray *nibsArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BOAFormCell" owner:self options:nil];
        self = nibsArray[0];
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        self.valueTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This obviously is resulting in a memory leak.

**If I put the loading code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, then it will make the ViewController as the owner of the xib.and it will look for outlets in the VC.**

I have already reused the cell in so many ViewControllers.

I want to avoid this leak, but I dont want all those VC to become individual owners of the xib and implement IBActions there and have properties for Outlets inside them.

Shall I make a static method that will just load the cell from xib and return it to me ?
but then how will I make the object as the owner of the xib ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your .xib file and then a class that inherit from `UITableViewCell` with same name than your .xib.

In the .xib, you will design your cell as you want. No ViewController, just a UIViewCell and its outlets.

Select your cell and in Utilities / Inspector, set the class of your cell to the name of your customized cell.

[image]

Now if you use the "Assistant editor", you will be able to drag and drop the outlet to the .h file to add properties to your customized cell.

In any class of your project, if you import the header of your brand new cell, you will be able to create customized cell by calling :

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
UITableViewCell *cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

(in this case, my files are named : CustomCell.h / CustomCell.m / CustomCell.xib)

The properties created for this customized cell are accessible like any properties of any class.

Comment: in your code, when you say "owner:self", you will change the ownership to the object executing the code.

There is no way, this is the answer to my question.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. You have a cell and you are using it in several ViewControllers? So you want its methods and action to be property of your cell and performed by your cell and not the VC that display the cell?

Comment: Yes. exactly. but wont [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil]; change the owner of the cell to the class I am writing the code in ?

Comment: What about creating a UIViewController whit a UITableCellView for its view? This ViewController will manage the outlets and methods. Then for the others controllers, you create basic cells, and add this view to their subview. So the customized cell's view is display in the controller you want but is manage by only one controller.

Comment: I found a solution. in the interface builder, I had the tableViewCell, i joined all the IBOutlets and IBActions to the cell which was the top level object.
So now irrespective of who the file owner is, the outlets and actions are looked for in the custom cell itself.

Answer (score 0):

in Your Tableview you can add this code for run your customcell i hope this works for you

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
            cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        CustomCell *cell =
            [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) 
    {
      NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }
cell.textLabel.text = @"Hi";

return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 6+ you should use this method:

```
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

Call it before loading the cells.

There are other methods likes this, where you can also register headers a footers, even cells generated programmatically registering the class with the tableview.

```
    - (void) viewDidLoad {

        ...
        [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellId" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
        {
            CustomCell *cell =
                [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId"
                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];
      }
```

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will always returns a cell, so there is no need to check for `cell == nil`